# ElasticSearch Query Creation

Tags: javascript, twitter, elasticsearch

I am having an inordinate amount of trouble trying to structure an ElasticSearch query.

I need to get the top 25 tweets based on the sum of two fields, `favoritesCount` and `retweetCount`.  I also need to be able to specify a date range on the field `postedCount`.

So far the closest I have been able to come is

```
 query = {
    'size' : 25,
    'fields' : ['retweetCount', 'favoritesCount', 'preferredUsername', 'body'],

    "query": {
        "range": { 
            "postedTime" : {
                'gte' : 'now-24M',
                'lte' : 'now'
            }
        }
    },
    "sort" : {
        "retweetCount" : {"order" : "desc"},
        "type" : "number",

    }

};
```

This query too many results and sorts on the total number of tweets with the same retweet count.  I also cannot figure out why this query doesn't return just the fields specified in the query.

Ideally, the query would return only the fields '['retweetCount', 'favoritesCount', 'preferredUsername', 'body']

Answer (score 0):

This is the query that you should trigger:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/index_name/type/_search' -d '{
"size" : 25,
"fields" : ["retweetCount", "favoritesCount", "preferredUsername", "body"],

"query": {
    "range": { 
        "postedTime" : {
            'gte' : 'now-24M',
            'lte' : 'now'
        }
    }
},
"sort" : {
    "retweetCount" : {"order" : "desc"},
    "type" : "number",

}
}'
```

Your are embedding everything inside query hash. This is not needed